# Not receiving sales order emails

Tags: magento

I am testing a Magento 1.6.2 installation, by making some test orders.

When the payment has gone through (via PayPal Standard), I get the order email sent to the customer and also the payment confirmation from PayPal, but I am not getting the emails to the store owner via Magento, i.e. the order email with the customers billing/shipping address and what

I have set the emails in `System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails`, but nothing is coming through.

Is there any other settings that need to be configured?

Comment: can you sent mail from that machine at all? Is there an MTA installed and configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are configure the smtp of your server. You can install a external smtp with the extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html an send the transaction email through gmail for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check **system** > **configuration** > **system** > **mail sending settings**

```
"disable email" should be "no"
```

if not working, your web host may need some extra configuration to send mail out.